# K-theory, proper class, set, isomorphism types

Tags: set-theory, k-theory

Define $K$ as the free abelian group with generators $[A],[A'],[A''],\dotsc$, the equivalence classes of isomorphism types, modulo $[A]=[A']+[A'']$
where
$0\to A'\to A \to A''\to0$
is a s.e.s. of modules in $R\mathsf{-Mod}$.
Is $K$ a set or a proper class?
What is all the $A$'s are from $R\mathsf{-mod}$ (the f.g. left $R$-modules); again is $K$ a set or a proper class? Why?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree with you,I clicked on rollback by mistake.Sorry.

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure what's the issue here. You have $K$ as a quotient of $F_3$. No?

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, the free group is not on 3 generators.The generators range through equivalence classes of isomorphism types of $R-modules$ and f.g. $R-modules$,respectively.My guess is that the first will be a proper class whereas the second will be a set.I would like to see why in general the first will be a proper class.

Comment: There are only set-many finitely generated modules (up to isomorphism).